# Chessboard configuartions with no possible capture on the next move

Tags: c, array, recursion, chess

**THE TASK:**

Given an NxM "chess"board and Q,R,B,K where Q is the number of queens, R the number of rooks, B the number of bishops, and K the number of knights ***find out how many possible configurations of such pieces there are where a capture isn't possible in the next move***. Even though this isn't really a chessboard or a chess game the same move ruleset still applies with one exception -  the pieces can all capture one another as if every piece was a separate color. The pieces are indistinguishable from one another so if I had 2 bishops on a 2x2 board like this:

bb

..

and swapped them around the board configuration would still be the same.

All the numbers N,M,Q,R,B,K are <= 10, the answer is expected to fit into *int* type and
the input goes like this:

N M

Q R B K

**EXAMPLES:**

**1** input:

2 2

0 0 2 0

output: 4

**2** input:

2 2

1 1 0 0

output: 0

**3** input:

2 2

0 0 0 2

output: 6

**4** input:

3 3

0 1 1 1

output: 24

**THE CODE:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//checking if a piece can be captured
int check(int n, int m, int poz_h[], int poz_w[], int poz_g[], int poz_s[], int poz_f[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    //checking if a queen can capture any piece
    while (poz_h[i] != -1)
    {
        int qR = poz_h[i]/1000;
        int qC = poz_h[i]%1000;
        while(poz_f[j] != -1)
        {
            int oR = poz_f[j]/1000;
            int oC = poz_f[j]%1000;
            if (qR == oR && qC == oC)
            {
                j++;
                continue;
            }
            if (qR == oR)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            if (qC == oC)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            if (abs(qR - oR) == abs(qC - oC))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            j++;
        }
        j = 0;
        i++;
    }
    i=0;
    //checking if a rook can capture any piece
    while (poz_w[i] != -1)
    {
        int rR = poz_w[i]/1000;
        int rC = poz_w[i]%1000;
        while(poz_f[j] != -1)
        {
            int oR = poz_f[j]/1000;
            int oC = poz_f[j]%1000;
            if (rR == oR && rC == oC)
            {
                j++;
                continue;
            }
            if (rR == oR)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            if (rC == oC)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            j++;
        }
        j = 0;
        i++;
    }
    i=0;
    //checking if a bishop can capture any piece
    while (poz_g[i]!=-1)
    {
        int bR = poz_g[i]/1000;
        int bC = poz_g[i]%1000;
        while(poz_f[j] != -1)
        {
            int oR = poz_f[j]/1000;
            int oC = poz_f[j]%1000;
            if (bR == oR && bC == oC)
            {
                j++;
                continue;
            }
            if (abs(bR - oR) == abs(bC - oC))
            {
                return 0;
            }
            j++;
        }
        j = 0;
        i++;
    }
    i=0;
    //checking if a knight can capture any piece
    while (poz_s[i]!=-1)
    {
        int nR = poz_s[i]/1000;
        int nC = poz_s[i]%1000;
        while(poz_f[j] != -1)
        {
            int oR = poz_f[j]/1000;
            int oC = poz_f[j]%1000;
            if (nR == oR && nC == oC)
            {
                j++;
                continue;
            }
            int X[8] = { 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1, 1, 2 };
            int Y[8] = { 1, 2, 2, 1, -1, -2, -2, -1 };
            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                int x = nR + X[i];
                int y = nC + Y[i];
                if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < n && y < m && x == oR && y == oC)
                {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
            j++;
        }
        j = 0;
        i++;
    }
    i=0;
    return 1;

}
long int suma = 0;

//checking for every possible combination
int take(int n, int m, int h, int w, int g, int s, char board[n][m], int przes_h, int przes_w, int przes_g, int przes_s, int poz_h[], int poz_w[], int poz_g[], int poz_s[], int poz_f[], int or_h, int or_w, int or_g, int or_s, int or_f)
{
    //starting with a queen, checking if there are any
    if (h>0)
    {
        for (int i = przes_h; i < n*m ;i++)
        {
            int j1 = i/m;
            int j2 = i%m;
            if (board[j1][j2] == 'o')
            {
                board[j1][j2] = 'q';
                //the przes_x is to make sure not to repeat the same configuration
                przes_h=j1*m+j2;
                //assigning the position of the queen in the array of queens, the chessboard won't be larger than 10x10 so doing it this way should be fine
                poz_h[or_h-h] = 1000*j1 + j2;
                //assigning the position of the queen in the array of all pieces
                poz_f[or_f-h-w-g-s] = 1000*j1 + j2;
                h--;
                //recursion for the next pieces
                take(n,m,h,w,g,s,board,przes_h,przes_w,przes_g,przes_s,poz_h,poz_w,poz_g,poz_s,poz_f,or_h,or_w,or_g,or_s,or_f);
                board[j1][j2] = 'o';
                h++;
                //next for loops should work the same way as this one
            }
        }
    }else if(w>0)
    {
        for (int i = przes_w; i < n*m ; i++)
        {
            int j1 = i/m;
            int j2 = i%m;
            if (board[j1][j2] == 'o')
            {
                board[j1][j2] = 'w';
                przes_w=j1*m+j2;
                poz_w[or_w-w] = 1000*j1 + j2;
                poz_f[or_f-h-w-g-s] = 1000*j1 + j2;
                w--;
                take(n,m,h,w,g,s,board,przes_h,przes_w,przes_g,przes_s,poz_h,poz_w,poz_g,poz_s,poz_f,or_h,or_w,or_g,or_s,or_f);
                board[j1][j2] = 'o';
                w++;
            }
        }
    }else if (g>0)
    {
        for (int i = przes_g; i < n*m ; i++)
        {
            int j1 = i/m;
            int j2 = i%m;
            if (board[j1][j2] == 'o')
            {
                board[j1][j2] = 'g';
                przes_g=j1*m+j2;
                poz_g[or_g-g] = 1000*j1 + j2;
                poz_f[or_f-h-w-g-s] = 1000*j1 + j2;
                g--;
                take(n,m,h,w,g,s,board,przes_h,przes_w,przes_g,przes_s,poz_h,poz_w,poz_g,poz_s,poz_f,or_h,or_w,or_g,or_s,or_f);
                board[j1][j2] = 'o';
                g++;
            }
        }
    }else if (s>0)
    {
        for (int i = przes_s; i < n*m ; i++)
        {
            int j1 = i/m;
            int j2 = i%m;
            if (board[j1][j2] == 'o')
            {
                board[j1][j2] = 'w';
                przes_s=j1*m+j2;
                poz_s[or_s-s] = 1000*j1 + j2;
                poz_f[or_f-h-w-g-s] = 1000*j1 + j2;
                s--;
                take(n,m,h,w,g,s,board,przes_h,przes_w,przes_g,przes_s,poz_h,poz_w,poz_g,poz_s,poz_f,or_h,or_w,or_g,or_s,or_f);
                board[j1][j2] = 'o';
                s++;
            }
        }
    }else
    //this else only triggers if there are no pieces left, which means I assigned every one of them a square on the chessboard
    {
        if (check(n,m,poz_h,poz_w,poz_g,poz_s,poz_f) == 1)
        {
            suma++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
int main() {

   int n,m;
   //this is just to not trigger the - Werror flag
   if (scanf("%d %d",&n,&m) == 800)
   {
       printf("yea");
   }
   char board[n][m];
   for (int i = 0; i < n;i++)
   {
       for (int j = 0; j < m;j++)
       {
           board[i][j] = 'o';
       }
   }
   int h,w,g,s;
   //this is just to not trigger the - Werror flag
   if (scanf(" %d %d %d %d",&h,&w,&g,&s)==800)
   {
       printf("yea");
   }
   int poz_h[h+1],poz_w[w+1],poz_g[g+1],poz_s[s+1],poz_f[h+w+g+s+1];
   poz_h[h] = -1;
   poz_w[w] = -1;
   poz_g[g] = -1;
   poz_s[s] = -1;
   poz_f[h+w+g+s] = -1;
   //checking if the user input is correct
   if (h+w+g+s>m*n)
   {
       printf("%d",0);
       return 0;
   }
   take(n,m,h,w,g,s,board,0,0,0,0,poz_h,poz_w,poz_g,poz_s,poz_f,h,w,g,s,h+w+g+s);
   printf("%ld",suma);
   return 0;
}
```

I would be grateful if someone could review my code, point out any glaring issues and maybe give some suggestions to improve it.

Answer (score 4):

## Naming things

Your code is full of one-letter variables and variables with very short names. It makes it very hard to understand the code. Consider this line on its own:

```
poz_f[or_f-h-w-g-s] = 1000*j1 + j2;
```

It's totally meaningless unless I read and try to understand the *whole program*. Maybe it makes a tiny bit more sense in your native language (I assume it's not english, why else would you rename Q, R, B and K from the problem statement to `h`, `w`, `g` and `s`?), but still I recommend you to use more descriptive variable names.

While writing the code, short names sound convenient, but for someone else reading the code, it makes it very hard. And I guarantee you that in half a year, you will have forgotten half of the code's meaning, so you yourself will have a hard time understanding your own code in the future.

## Give your code more structure

Your program now consists of a few very large functions, passing around lots of variables. You can improve this by creating `struct`s to group related variables together, and by creating more helper functions to split up and simplify the large functions.

You could create a `struct Board` that holds all the state of a board, for example holding all the `poz_*[]` arrays. You can also create a `struct Position` that holds the row and column indices as separate variables, so you no longer have to multiply and divide integers by 1000 to pack those into a single `int`. The latter is bad both for performance and the fact that you have unnecessarily limited the maximum size of the board.

## Implement proper error handling

This is very dangerous:

```
//this is just to not trigger the - Werror flag
if (scanf("%d %d",&n,&m) == 800)
{
    printf("yea");
}
```

The point about warnings is that they point to potentially unsafe behavior. If you use `-Werror`, that means you are interested in making your code safe. If you instead not fix the problem but actively ignore it like you do in your code, you made your code less safe as the problem is still there, but the compiler now no longer sees it. This is worse than just disabling the compiler warnings!

The poper way to fix this is not even hard:

```
if (scanf("%d %d",&n,&m) != 2)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not read board dimension!\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```